# How do you find the area of the largest square?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, puzzle

[image]

What formulas/theorems are to be used?

Comment: What's your take on the problem. Did you try anything that didn't work. If so add those efforts into your question for context's sake

Comment: Have you tried considering all the similar right triangles?

Comment: @Plato [The question is tagged "puzzle"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1190/280596).

Comment: Challenge to the users alright. My apologies @Macklemore

Comment: No harm, no foul, @Plato.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Note that $DF = EF=x$, i.e.

$$4\sin a  + \frac 4{\cos a} = 3 \cos a + \frac3{\sin a}=x$$

which leads to $\tan a = \frac34$ and $x=\frac{37}5$. Thus, the area is

$$x^2 =\frac{1369}{25}$$

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how you came to $\tan a=\frac{3}{4}$ Could you please provide a small helpful hint towards that fact?

Comment: @Plato - rearrange the equation as $4\frac{\sin a  \cos a + 1}{\cos a} = 3 \frac{\sin a \cos a + 1}{\sin a}$.

Comment: That, that is more than a hint. Thank you

Comment: +1. That's how I solved it ... then I noticed that there's some interesting geometry going on in the figure that the algebra breezes past. For instance, the triangles adjacent to point $F$ are actually *congruent*; and the product of the sub-segments of $DF$ (and $EF$) is the product of the sides of the squares. However, I haven't (yet?) found a way to exploit such observations into a particularly insightful solution; certainly nothing more *efficient* than what you have.

Comment: @Blue - that’s a nice observation. Thanks